# In TypeScript how do I declare a generic with 2 arguments, where the first is a key of the second that returns a specific type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, keyof

I'm looking to have a generic class like this one:

```js
export abstract class Foo<ID extends keyof T, T> {
    bar(T t) {
        const s: string = t[ID];
    }
}
```

Obviously the code above can't infer the type of `t[ID]` and we're getting an implicit `any`.
How can I enforce using generics `T[ID]` will be a `string`?

Comment: This isn't valid TypeScript, I assume you mean `T t` to be `t: T`, but where do you expect the value for `t[ID]` to come from? Is `id` an argument or class property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile so I changed it to something that will:

```
export abstract class Foo<ID extends string, T extends Record<ID, string>> {

  // add a property of type ID.
  constructor(public id: ID) { } 

  // change the Java-esque (T t) to (t: T)
  bar(t: T) {
    //use the id property to index t; can't use type ID at runtime
    const s: string = t[this.id]; 
  }

}
```

The way to enforce the relationship you want is: instead of constraining `ID` to `keyof T`, you constrain `T` to `Record<ID, string>` where `Record<K, V>` is a type from [the standard TypeScript library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1361-L1366) describing any object with keys from `K` and values from `V`.  Hope that helps.  Good luck.